# Tomcat and GlassFish not working together

Tags: tomcat, servlets, glassfish

I have Tomcat 8.0.15.0, Glassfish 4.1 and NetBeans 8.0.2 installed on my PC, which I installed simultaneously from Netbeans.org.

All three don't seem to be working together well on my PC as the following problem scenario illustrates:

With Netbeans inactive, I ran startup.bat from the Tomcat Program/bin folder and Tomcat page appeared on Web at http://localhost:8080 as expected.

I then created a project FirstServlet in NetBeans using the Tomcat library where I coded a servlet.  When I run the project I get the following error message:

**C:\Users\Jon\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FirstServletApp\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1045: Deployment error: Starting of Tomcat failed.**

I created a second project with a different name and identical functionality using the Glassfish library. but when I tried to run, I got the error message:

**Could not start GlassFish Server 4.1: HTTP or HTTPS listener port is occupied while server is not running.**

I then ran shutdown.bat from Tomcat Program/bin folder and returned to NetBeans and was able to run the second project successfully and on the Web the Glasssish page appears on http://localhost:8080.

How I can set things up so I can create projects using either Tomcat or Glassfish library in NetBeans and can successfully run both?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change the ports for Tomcat. It is opening 3 ports : 8005, 8080 and 8009. Open the conf/server.xml file and change those values. After the next start, the conflicts shouldn't appear anymore.

You may have a look at the complete documentation of Tomcat connectors ([http](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html), [ajp](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/ajp.html)).

If you prefer to change the port on the Glassfish size, you'll have to open the glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain.xml file, and change the port attribute of the network-listener(s).

Comment: They have usage of port 8080 in common.  What is a valid number to change to?  Also, when I bring up the xml file in xml editor I can only look at it on the Web.  What editor should I use to modify it?

Comment: You may use any text advanced editor. On Windows : Notepad++, UltraEdit, PSpad,...

Comment: Technically, you can put any valid port number, as far as it solves the conflict. Practically, put 8081 or 8180, which are very common.

Comment: I changed all instances of port 8080 to 8081 in Tomcat/conf/server.xml and rebooted my PC and brought up NetBeans again and still got the same error when I tried to run project which uses Tomcat library: C:\Users\Jon\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FirstServletApp\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1045: Deployment error: Starting of Tomcat failed.

Comment: In fact you have 2 problems : the conflict is solved and the first problem remains. You should have asked separate questions.
For the other problem, you should have a look to the logs. Dou you have a catalina.out file ?

Comment: In what folder would this file be located ?

Comment: In tomcat log's directory.

Comment: Here is part of my log file:21-Feb-2015 07:30:41.493 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer Could not contact localhost:8005. Tomcat may not be running.
21-Feb-2015 07:30:41.493 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer Catalina.stop: 
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
 at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
 at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect21-Feb-2015  ... more log follows

Comment: When try to start Tomcat from Netbeans:  get error: '127.0.0.1' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Found solution to second problem.  Right click on Server Apache Tomcat,  select properties, platform and unclick Use IDE Proxy Settings. Thanks for help.